# How to Activate a specific Workbook on non-VBA Excel Quit

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook ("CodeBook.xlsm") that runs code using a BeforeSave event.  When a user has multiple workbooks open and chooses to quit excel via File/Exit, the user is prompted whether to save workbooks, and if yes to CodeBook.xlsm, then the BeforeSave code is run. The problem is, at that point the ActiveWorkbook may not be CodeBook.xlsm, unless that happens to be the workbook that the user was in when he/she selected Exit Excel.  If the user quit excel from another workbook, the BeforeSave code is running but the activeworkbook is some random file of the user, so all the references to specific worksheets and ranges in the BeforeSave code do not work.

I have tried various ways using a Static declaration to retain the name of CodeBook and workbook().activate to activate it when the application is quitting, but when BeforeSave runs, it can't pick up the name CodeBook anywhere, short of hard-coding the name into the code.

Any suggestions?  How to retain a variable name in memory when there is no code running, but is there when a user initiates a quit excel, OR how to activate a specific workbook when Excel is quitting from a user command and not from application.quit.  Using excel 2010.

Comment: VBA is attached to a specific workbook and becomes active and accessible when this workbook is active. Imagine that you have two functions with the same name attached to the same event, one belongs to workbook "A" while the other to workbook "B". Is this legal? Of course it is!!! To maintain consistency, the **current scope** of Excel is that of the active workbook. The only solution I can think of is to build a plug-in to Excel itself which will be accessible as soon as you open Excel (with or without a file).

Answer (score 0):

I overcame this by including a reference to the specific workbook.

For example, this code simply saves the date/time stamp in cell `A1` of `Sheet1` before closing the document.  By adding `ThisWorkbook`, it works on the specific workbook that the code resides in.  If you don't add `ThisWorkbook` then it will work on the active workbook when the user quits.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Now()
End Sub
```

---

Place this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

[image]